# Merge mongodb aggregation results of unread messages count per conversation member into document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation, messaging

I want to aggregate unread messages count per member in a conversation group and seems my aggregation pipeline is working correctly, but, I don't know how to achieve the following results.

Please check the example.

Thread documents

```json
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60d4efa6a95f446051f31492"),
    "latestMessage" : "Voluptatem eos officiis optio dolor est et.",
    "type" : "FEED",
    "users" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60d4efa6a95f446051f31491"),
            "displayName" : "Monique Connelly II"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60d4efa6a95f446051f31490"),
            "displayName" : "Ivory Jacobson DDS"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60d4efa6a95f446051f3148f"),
            "displayName" : "Ron Weimann"
        }
    ],
    "createdBy" : "60d4efa6a95f446051f3148f",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-06-24T20:48:38.537Z"),
    "modifiedAt" : ISODate("2021-06-24T20:48:38.620Z"),
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60d4efa6a95f446051f31493"),
    "type" : "CONVERSATION",
    "users" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60d4efa6a95f446051f31491"),
            "displayName" : "Monique Connelly II"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60d4efa6a95f446051f31490"),
            "displayName" : "Ivory Jacobson DDS"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60d4efa6a95f446051f3148f"),
            "displayName" : "Ron Weimann"
        }
    ],
    "createdBy" : "60d4efa6a95f446051f3148f",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-06-24T20:48:38.569Z"),
    "modifiedAt" : ISODate("2021-06-24T20:48:38.569Z"),
}
```

Message documents

```json
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60d4efa6a95f446051f31494"),
    "content" : "Itaque rerum facere neque fuga aspernatur dolorum.",
    "deleted" : false,
    "threadId" : ObjectId("60d4efa6a95f446051f31492"),
    "type" : "TEXT",
    "thread" : {
        "$ref" : "threads",
        "$id" : ObjectId("60d4efa6a95f446051f31492")
    },
    "readBy" : [ 
        ObjectId("60d4efa6a95f446051f3148f")
    ],
    "attributes" : [],
    "createdBy" : "60d4efa6a95f446051f3148f",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-06-24T20:48:38.598Z"),
    "modifiedAt" : ISODate("2021-06-24T20:48:38.598Z"),
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60d4efa6a95f446051f31495"),
    "content" : "Nisi suscipit iste magni voluptatem.",
    "deleted" : false,
    "threadId" : ObjectId("60d4efa6a95f446051f31492"),
    "type" : "TEXT",
    "thread" : {
        "$ref" : "threads",
        "$id" : ObjectId("60d4efa6a95f446051f31492")
    },
    "readBy" : [ 
        ObjectId("60d4efa6a95f446051f3148f")
    ],
    "attributes" : [],
    "createdBy" : "60d4efa6a95f446051f3148f",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-06-24T20:48:38.610Z"),
    "modifiedAt" : ISODate("2021-06-24T20:48:38.610Z"),
}

and more...
```

My aggregation pipeline

```json
db.threads.aggregate([
    { "$lookup": { "from": "messages", "localField": "_id", "foreignField": "threadId", "as": "message"}},    
    { "$unwind": "$message" },
    { "$unwind": "$users" },
    { "$unwind": "$message.readBy" },
    
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {        
            "user_id": "$users._id",         
            "thread_id": "$_id",    
        }, 
        "unread_messages": {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$ne": [ "$users._id", "$message.readBy" ] },
                    1,
                    0
                ]
            }
        }
    }},      
//     { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": { "$mergeObjects": ["$_id", { "count": "$unread_messages" }]} } }
])
```

Aggregation results

```json
{
    "_id" : {
        "user_id" : ObjectId("60d4efa6a95f446051f31491"),
        "thread_id" : ObjectId("60d4efa6a95f446051f31492")
    },
    "unread_messages" : 4.0
},
{
    "_id" : {
        "user_id" : ObjectId("60d4efa6a95f446051f3148f"),
        "thread_id" : ObjectId("60d4efa6a95f446051f31492")
    },
    "unread_messages" : 4.0
},
{
    "_id" : {
        "user_id" : ObjectId("60d4efa6a95f446051f31490"),
        "thread_id" : ObjectId("60d4efa6a95f446051f31492")
    },
    "unread_messages" : 4.0
}
```

Results are partially OK, but, I want to keep my original structure of a document and copy aggregation results accordingly to the thread id back to the original document

I would be very grateful if you help me with the aggregation pipeline

Expected results

```json
{
    "_id": ObjectId("60d4efa6a95f446051f31492"),
    "latestMessage": "Voluptatem eos officiis optio dolor est et.",
    "type": "LISTING",
    "users": [{
            "_id": ObjectId("60d4efa6a95f446051f31491"),
            "displayName": "Monique Connelly II"
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("60d4efa6a95f446051f31490"),
            "displayName": "Ivory Jacobson DDS"
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("60d4efa6a95f446051f3148f"),
            "displayName": "Ron Weimann"
        }
    ],
    "createdBy": "60d4efa6a95f446051f3148f",
    "createdAt": ISODate("2021-06-24T20:48:38.537Z"),
    "modifiedAt": ISODate("2021-06-24T20:48:38.620Z"),
    "message": [...],
    "stats": [{
            "_id": {
                "user_id": ObjectId("60d4efa6a95f446051f31491"),
                "thread_id": ObjectId("60d4efa6a95f446051f31492")
            },
            "unread_messages": 4.0
        },
        {
            "_id": {
                "user_id": ObjectId("60d4efa6a95f446051f3148f"),
                "thread_id": ObjectId("60d4efa6a95f446051f31492")
            },
            "unread_messages": 4.0
        },
        {
            "_id": {
                "user_id": ObjectId("60d4efa6a95f446051f31490"),
                "thread_id": ObjectId("60d4efa6a95f446051f31492")
            },
            "unread_messages": 4.0
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You can try this: use `$push: "$$ROOT"` into a variable called `doc` in the `$group` stage and see what results. Maybe you can do _projection_ from it and further work on it.

Comment: Can you share sample documents from the `messages` collection too? Not only is what you are looking for achievable, but your query can be optimized.

Comment: Udpated my post

Answer (score 0):

I post a solution that works perfectly for my case with $first + $replateRoot operations.
Final results have different ids as not in the first post that is because I re-created documents

```json
db.threads.aggregate([
    { "$lookup": { "from": "messages", "localField": "_id", "foreignField": "threadId", "as": "message"}},    
    { "$unwind": "$message" },
    { "$unwind": "$users" },
    { "$unwind": "$message.readBy" },  
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {        
            "user_id": "$users._id",         
            "thread_id": "$_id",    
        },
        "thread": { 
            "$first": "$$ROOT" 
        }, 
        "unread_messages": {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$ne": [ "$users._id", "$message.readBy" ] },
                    1,
                    0
                ]
            }
        }
    }}, 
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.thread_id",
        "thread": { "$first": "$thread" },    
        "stats": {
            "$push": {
                "userId": "$_id.user_id",
                "unreadMessages": "$unread_messages"
            }
        }
    }},      
    { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": { "$mergeObjects": ["$thread", { stats: "$stats" }]} } }
])
```

Final results

```json
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60d574e242e59a48b886c586"),
    "latestMessage" : "Molestias quo quod occaecati exercitationem veniam eaque.",
    "type" : "LISTING",
    "users" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("60d574e242e59a48b886c584"),
        "displayName" : "Meggan Vandervort"
    },
    "unreadMessages" : NumberLong(0),
    "createdBy" : "60d574e242e59a48b886c582",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-06-25T06:17:06.547Z"),
    "modifiedAt" : ISODate("2021-06-25T06:17:06.617Z")
    "message" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("60d574e242e59a48b886c58d"),
        "content" : "Velit dolores vel.",
        "deleted" : false,
        "threadId" : ObjectId("60d574e242e59a48b886c586"),
        "type" : "TEXT",
        "thread" : {
            "$ref" : "threads",
            "$id" : ObjectId("60d574e242e59a48b886c586")
        },
        "readBy" : ObjectId("60d574e242e59a48b886c582"),
        "attributes" : [],
        "createdBy" : "60d574e242e59a48b886c582",
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-06-25T06:17:06.595Z"),
        "modifiedAt" : ISODate("2021-06-25T06:17:06.595Z")
    },
    "stats" : [ 
        {
            "userId" : ObjectId("60d574e242e59a48b886c584"),
            "unreadessages" : 6.0
        }, 
        {
            "userId" : ObjectId("60d574e242e59a48b886c583"),
            "unreadessages" : 6.0
        }, 
        {
            "userId" : ObjectId("60d574e242e59a48b886c582"),
            "unreadessages" : 6.0
        }
    ]
}

 and more...
```